# exception handler method in @ControllerAdvice are not get called

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception, junit5

I'm test my controller using junit5. In test method, `EntityNotFoundException` is throwed but exception handler is not called.
I have tried declaring `ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver` bean with order 1. But it didn't works.

Exception handler which handles `EntityNotFoundException`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppWideExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
    public @ResponseBody
    String handleEntityNotFoundException(EntityNotFoundException e) {
        return "test";
    }
    ...
}
```

The `AppWideExceptionHandler` is in `youshu.exception` package which will be scanned because of `@ComponentScan({"youshu.controller", "youshu.service","youshu.exception"})` annotated on `WebConfig` class.

The `processRefundApplication` controller method calls `RefundService.get(String orderID)` which may throw `EntityNotFoundException`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/Order")
public class OrderController {
    @AsSeller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{orderID}/RefundApplication",
            method = RequestMethod.PATCH,
            params = "isApproved",
            produces = "application/json")
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = RuntimeException.class)
    public @ResponseBody
    Map processRefundApplication(@SessionAttribute("user") User user,
                                 @PathVariable("orderID") String orderID,
                                 @RequestParam("isApproved") boolean isApproved) {
        ...
    }
```

debug information:

```
...
17:58:34.575 [main] DEBUG org.apache.ibatis.datasource.pooled.PooledDataSource - Returned connection 5312115 to pool.
17:58:34.576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.Map youshu.controller.OrderController.processRefundApplication(youshu.entity.User,java.lang.String,boolean)]: youshu.exception.EntityNotFoundException: 找不到订单ID为20180419182220001的退款申请
17:58:34.576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.Map youshu.controller.OrderController.processRefundApplication(youshu.entity.User,java.lang.String,boolean)]: youshu.exception.EntityNotFoundException: 找不到订单ID为20180419182220001的退款申请
17:58:34.576 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.util.Map youshu.controller.OrderController.processRefundApplication(youshu.entity.User,java.lang.String,boolean)]: youshu.exception.EntityNotFoundException: 找不到订单ID为20180419182220001的退款申请
17:58:34.577 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
youshu.exception.EntityNotFoundException: 找不到订单ID为20180419182220001的退款申请
    at youshu.service.RefundService.get(RefundService.java:23) ~[classes/:?]
    ...
```

test class:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebConfig.class, RootConfig.class, DataConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
class OrderControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    OrderController controller;
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    OrderService orderService;
    private User customer;
    private User seller;
    private HashMap<String, Object> sessionAttrs;
    private ResultMatcher success = jsonPath("$.code")
            .value("0");
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @BeforeEach
    void init() {
        if (customer == null) {
            customer = new User();
            customer.setID(18222);
            customer.setName("shijiliyq");
            customer.setPassword("...");
            customer.setPaymentPassword("...");
        }
        if (seller == null) {
            seller = new User();
            seller.setID(27895);
        }
        if (sessionAttrs == null) {
            sessionAttrs = new HashMap<>();
            sessionAttrs.put("user", customer);
        }
        if (mockMvc == null)
            mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();

    }
    @Test
    void processRefundApplication() throws Exception{
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

        String path = String.format("/Order/%s%d0001/RefundApplication"
                , simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()), customer.getID());
        HashMap<String,Object> sessionAttributes=new HashMap<>();
        sessionAttributes.put("user",seller);
        mockMvc.perform(patch(path)
                .characterEncoding("UTF-8")
                .param("isApproved","true")
                .sessionAttrs(sessionAttributes))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(success);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: where do you set up mockMvc?

Comment: @Plog in `init()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to point your mockMvc instance to your controller advice class:

```
@Autowired
AppWideExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

...

mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).setControllerAdvice(exceptionHandler).build();
```